# Using Score + GUID As RowKey for a Game that uses Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-storage, query-performance, azure-table-storage

I want to create a game that uses Azure Table Storage for the leaderboard.

It has been recommended that if I want Azure Table Storage to present me with a sorted / paged list, I need to use the score as the RowKey for my table entity. (I am going to append a player GUID to ensure that each generated RowKey is unique.)

Here are my concerns with this recommendation:

- Other players can affect a player's score (like decreasing it), so there may be concurrency concerns to be considered. If a game client tries to update a player's score, and I use the previous score to search for the table entity, I might not be able to find that row if another client has already updated it.
- If use another field to search for the table entity (partition + attribute), such as player name, then the query isn't going to be optimal.

Which is a better approach for performing row updates? Should I try to use locking techniques and search by RowKey? Or do I search using the username?

Or, should I abandon the idea of using score as RowKey and do the sorting in memory after retrieving a full table to display a page in the Leaderboard?

Assume, for the moment, that the score updates and leaderboard viewing are equally frequent.

Comment: I ended up using Partition + Attribute query as the first thing to do within a retry cycle, then do the updates within that block. If it fails for whatever reason, it tries getting the entity again using the same query. It exits after a number of retries. It's not efficient but it's the only way I can think of without resorting to singleton solutions like Azure Queue + a single continuously running Webjob, which require at least a Basic instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not appropriate to leverage `RowKey` or `PartitionKey` to satisfy your requirement. As the combination of partition key and row key is the identity of the entity in table storage. Once you define them in the insert operation, you can never update again. Refer to the thread on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7ad92641-3b0b-4faa-989f-3506fab47325/can-we-update-partition-key-or-row-key-in-azure-table-storage?forum=windowsazuredata for detailed explanation.

Additionally, as the description at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#sorting-data-in-the-table-service:

> The Table service returns entities sorted in ascending order based on PartitionKey and then by RowKey.

So the Azure Table Storage is not so appropriate in your scenario. You can leverage [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't update partition or row keys, and that I have to destroy the record and insert a new one if I need to change either. I have chosen to work around these limitations with Azure Table Storage for cost and scalability reasons.

Comment: Cool, could you please share your idea as your answer, which will benefit other communities in the similar scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I have chosen to work WITH these limitations with Azure Table Storage for cost and scalability reasons (instead of Azure SQL)."

Answer (score 0):

I imagined a solution for implementing a leaderboard using Azure Tables. I'd hate to have to integrate Redis or SQL server into an MMO just for the sake of scalable leaderboards. Leaderboards are useful for a multitude of problems in MMO's, so it'd be awesome to have a scalable and cheap solution that uses azure tables for storage.

The solution I imagined will use two (or three) tables:

1. A table containing the following fields:
   playerId (RowKey and PartitionKey is a has of it)
   currentScore (double). That is used to lookup the score of a player directly.
2. A table containing the following fields:
   PartitionKey = ID of leaf node of binary tree described in 3
   RowKey = LeadingZeros(Score) + "_" + LeadingZeros(PlayerId)
3. Somewhere in azure (tables) as well create a binary tree. Store the following information:

   - Node Id
   - MaxScore (within this node)
   - MinScore (within this node)
   - Score Count (number of scores stored within this node, *only if it's a leaf node*)

The above is the overall idea of how it could be stored. Now, handling concurrency updating it could be resolved by using concurrency mechanism of azure table itself (if the binary tree is stored within it). It may be possible to use a third azure table to store the binary tree nodes as well, one per record, rather than storing the partition tree in a single row. Obviously, the way this binary tree would grow would be by limiting how many players are added to each leaf node.

There are questions to be answered about this solution as it hasn't been implemented, I see insertion / update performance being a potentially interesting problem.

Read performance could be addressed by simply caching the results and updating it every few seconds, which is acceptable by most applications using leaderboards.

Then finally, in an ideal world, wrap all this complicated structure around a very easy to use code that allows you to create as many leaderboards as you like in your project without the cost and hassle of Redis and SQL.

Later on in the year I will probably try my hand at implementing something like the above solution, if no one has replied to this thread with some functional C# code before by the time I get to it :)